# Problem when initializing properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I keep getting this error:
CS0501: 'jQueryUploadTest.Upload.FilesStatus.thumbnail_url.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern

I have this exact code outside of my sharepoint project in its own separate website and it works fine.  Whenever I try to implement it in my sharepoint project i get that error.

Here is the code for my upload.ashx file:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="jQueryUploadTest.Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace jQueryUploadTest {

    public class Upload : IHttpHandler {
        public class FilesStatus
        {
            public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int size { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string delete_url { get; set; }
            public string delete_type { get; set; }
            public string error { get; set; }
            public string progress { get; set; }
        }
        private readonly JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        private string ingestPath;
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
            //var r = context.Response;
            ingestPath = @"C:\temp\ingest\";

            context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");

            HandleMethod(context);
        }

        private void HandleMethod (HttpContext context) {
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod) {
                case "HEAD":
                case "GET":
                    ServeFile(context);
                    break;

                case "POST":
                    UploadFile(context);
                    break;

                case "DELETE":
                    DeleteFile(context);
                    break;

                default:
                    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void DeleteFile (HttpContext context) {
            string filePath = ingestPath + context.Request["f"];
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }

        private void UploadFile (HttpContext context) {
            List<FilesStatus> statuses = new List<FilesStatus>();
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers = context.Request.Headers;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headers["X-File-Name"])) {
                UploadWholeFile(context, statuses);
            } else {
                UploadPartialFile(headers["X-File-Name"], context, statuses);
            }


            WriteJsonIframeSafe(context, statuses);
        }

        private void UploadPartialFile (string fileName, HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count != 1) throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Attempt to upload chunked file containing more than one fragment per request");
            Stream inputStream = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
            string fullName = ingestPath + Path.GetFileName(fileName);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                while (l > 0) {
                    fs.Write(buffer,0,l);
                    l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                }
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }
            FilesStatus MyFileStatus = new FilesStatus();
            MyFileStatus.thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            MyFileStatus.url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            MyFileStatus.name = fileName;
            MyFileStatus.size = (int)(new FileInfo(fullName)).Length;
            MyFileStatus.type = "image/png";
            MyFileStatus.delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            MyFileStatus.delete_type = "DELETE";
            MyFileStatus.progress = "1.0";

          /*  {
                thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                name = fileName,
                size = (int)(new FileInfo(fullName)).Length,
                type = "image/png",
                delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                delete_type = "DELETE",
                progress = "1.0"
            };
            */
            statuses.Add(MyFileStatus);

        }

        private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++) {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[i];
                file.SaveAs(ingestPath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                FilesStatus MyFileStatus = new FilesStatus();
                MyFileStatus.thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fileName;
                MyFileStatus.url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
                MyFileStatus.name = fileName;
                MyFileStatus.size = file.ContentLength;
                MyFileStatus.type = "image/png";
                MyFileStatus.delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName;
                MyFileStatus.delete_type = "DELETE";
                MyFileStatus.progress = "1.0";
                statuses.Add(MyFileStatus);
            }
        }

        private void WriteJsonIframeSafe(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Vary", "Accept");
            try {
                if (context.Request["HTTP_ACCEPT"].Contains("application/json")) {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                } else {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                }
            } catch {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            }

            string jsonObj = js.Serialize(statuses.ToArray());
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
        }

        private void ServeFile (HttpContext context) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["f"])) ListCurrentFiles(context);
            else DeliverFile(context);
        }

        private void DeliverFile (HttpContext context) {
            string filePath = ingestPath + context.Request["f"];
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment, filename=\"" + context.Request["f"] + "\"");
            } else {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }
        }

        private void ListCurrentFiles (HttpContext context) {
            List<FilesStatus> files = new List<FilesStatus>();

            string[] names = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\ingest", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (string name in names) {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(name);
                FilesStatus MyFileStatus = new FilesStatus();
                MyFileStatus.thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.name = f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.size = (int)f.Length;
                MyFileStatus.type = "image/png";
                MyFileStatus.delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name;
                MyFileStatus.delete_type = "DELETE";

                files.Add(MyFileStatus);
                /*files.Add(new FilesStatus
                {
                    thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    name = f.Name,
                    size = (int)f.Length,
                    type = "image/png",
                    delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    delete_type = "DELETE"
                });*/
            }

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline, filename=\"files.json\"");
            string jsonObj = js.Serialize(files.ToArray());
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked my Version targeting and its asp.net 3.5, I went to properties in my project and its 3.5 so I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: please post _minimal_ examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized what was going on when I spotted this line:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="jQueryUploadTest.Upload" %>
```

You're making a page handle (probably `*.ashx`) and it is - no doubt - being compiled under ASP.Net 1.1 application pool. This doesn't support C# 3.0 constructs, and thus it fails.

See if you can move the website to an ASP.Net 2.0 application pool. The problem should go away. Be aware that there are - minor - incompatible changes between frameworks 1.1 and 2.0 that might require you to adjust your web.config and minor other details.

I you dont want that, the most straightforward way is to simply don't use the C# 3.0 style construct:

```
public class FilesStatus
{

    private string m_thumbnail_url;
    private string m_name;
    private string m_url;
    private int m_size;
    private string m_type;
    private string m_delete_url;
    private string m_delete_type;
    private string m_error;
    private string m_progress;

    public string m_thumbnailurl { get { return m_thumbnail_url; } set { m_thumbnail_url = value; } }
    public string name { get { return m_name; } set { m_name = value; } }
    public string url { get { return m_url; } set { m_url = value; } }
    public int size { get { return m_size; } set { m_size = value; } }
    public string type { get { return m_type; } set { m_type = value; } }
    public string m_deleteurl { get { return m_delete_url; } set { m_delete_url = value; } }
    public string m_deletetype { get { return m_delete_type; } set { m_delete_type = value; } }
    public string error { get { return m_error; } set { m_error = value; } }
    public string progress { get { return m_progress; } set { m_progress = value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Although a minor possibility, this is probably not it. I suggest you look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615984/problem-when-initializing-properties/6616445#6616445) first.

The problem seems to be that your framework version is different for the sharepoint project. See if you can target framework 3.5 or higher.

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects. When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

So this:

```
 public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
```

will only work in an abstract class (with the abstract keyword) or interface (without the public keyword); In C# 3.0+ it will generate an anonymous backing field instead

### Update

I just tried to make it plausible that you could be targetting the 3.5 framework, while still using the C# pre-3.0 language specification. I don't have Visual Studio right now, but I used monodevelop:

[image]

I can only imagine that Visual Studio has a similar option (hidden) somewhere, and the error message is slightly less helpful

Comment: Added 'evidence' that Framework version does not necessarily imply language level